# Is there a good reason to use a culture-sensitive comparer for strings?

Tags: c#, .net, string, comparison, cultureinfo

After digging through the .NET code, I found that the comparer generated by `Comparer<string>.Default` and the implementation of `string.CompareTo` uses culture-sensitive string comparison (specifically, sensitive to `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`). Default behavior of ordered sets and maps is to use this comparer.

However, F#'s ordered `Set` and `Map` create a special comparer for strings that uses `String.CompareOrdinal`. Consequentially, these collections are a lot faster when working with string keys than the recent `System.Collections.Immutable` sorted dictionary and sorted map, as can be seen from the following chart:

[Chart](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vcgoze324sqs9bi/077.MapLike.MapSingle.png?dl=0)

I'm working on a library of immutable collections as well (it's called Funq in the chart). Before I performed this optimization, I had the same performance problems as those collections.

Will this optimization cause any issues, considering that I definitely want to maintain the expected ordering in an ordered collection? Can you give specific examples that won't behave as expected, in specific cultures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

`"a"` vs `"B"` sorts differently using `CompareOrdinal` than with CurrentCulture, InvariantCulture, and InvariantCulture ignoring case.

Demonstration: http://rextester.com/QSCF42204

```
string a = "a";
string b = "B";
Console.WriteLine(Comparer<string>.Default.Compare(a, b));
Console.WriteLine(string.CompareOrdinal(a, b));
Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(a, b, true, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(a, b, false, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize it was so simple! Why is `"a" < "B"` in the `InvariantCulture`? Or rather, who decided that `"a" < "A"`?

Comment: @JustGreg: Because `"azalea"` comes before `"Bali"` in the dictionary (pick any Western language, pick any dictionary).  Or encyclopedia.

Comment: @JustGreg: Why do you think that `"a" < "B"` is related to `"a" < "A"`?  And why do you think that `"a" < "A"` (in some of these, it isn't)

Comment: sorry, I'm being an idiot for some reason. Too little sleep probably. I ran http://rextester.com/DHJK8080 and found that `"A" > "a"` (case-sensitive). I guess it sort of makes sense. It doesn't really matter. Are you familiar with examples from other cultures? Also, what do you think the 'expected' ordering would be? As a programmer, ordinal comparisons make more sense, and I would personally expect `a` to appear after `B`.

Comment: As a programmer, I'm familiar with the ordinal ordering, but it doesn't mean I would ever use it for data presented to a user.